# Embedded and Embeddable data not stored in the database

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am Learning java-spring boot and i was able to store the normal data in db. but i wasn't able to store the complex json data.

the json data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "address": {
        "street": "Kulas Light",
        "city": "Gwenborough"
    }
}
```

User.java

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "User_tbl")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "Address")
    private Address address;
}
```

Address.java

```
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
}
```

UserController.java

```
import com.example.JsonParser.model.User;
import com.example.JsonParser.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public Iterable<User> list() {
        return userService.list();
    }
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public User save(User user){

        return userService.add(user);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
import com.example.JsonParser.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

UserService.java

```
import com.example.JsonParser.model.User;
import com.example.JsonParser.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;
    public Iterable<User> list() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    public Iterable<User> save(List<User> users) {
        return repo.saveAll(users);
    }

    public User add(User user) {
        repo.save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: 'true'
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:Ramesh
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: 'true'
```

when i send the post request with json data

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "address": {
        "street": "Kulas Light",
        "city": "Gwenborough"
    }
}
```

i got response as

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": null,
    "address": null
}
```

H2 db:
[image]
also, the db is empty what i should modify or add in order to store the data?

Comment: You are not saving the data as a JSON string, you are saving an instance of a class into the DB. Can you check whether both tables are having the data after the POST request is successfully sent?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran actually only one table created which has columns `name,id,city,street`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that the data from the request is not reaching the Controller. If you put a breakpoint in your `save` method you can see that all the attributes inside the `User` will be null. So the first thing you need to do is to annotate the method argument with this `@RequestBody`, so automatically the JSON data will be converted to your Bean (given that the fields are having the same name).

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public User save(@RequestBody User user){

    return userService.add(user);
}
```

Second thing is that both your `User` and `Address` class should be annotated with `@NoArgsConstructor`.

So once you've done both the issue will be solved, and data will be saved and retrieved properly.

Comment: i missed `@RequestBody` annotation kinda feeling dumb. and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have created Two Entity Classes. First, you have to save the Address and then take Address Instance and set it in the User Entity class and then save it.
OR
Make address as a string instead of Entity class and Try to Pass the data as JSON String to the controller so that I will save it as JSON String

```
   public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
}

{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "address": "{    "street": "Kulas Light",    "city": "Gwenborough"  }"   
}
```

Comment: There is only one entity class and the annotations Embedded and Embeddable are used to save the data into a single table.

Comment: yes but instead creating another classes you can just add as a string and when you are try to get record you can just map to any any other classes

Comment: @FaisalBehram it was more complex for  complex json data.